# Triggering 2nd job activity if 1st one aborts

Tags: datastage

I have two job activities in my sequence job.
I want run 2nd job activity if 1st job activity aborted due env. issue or manually.

Can anyone help how i can implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect a link ("trigger") from Job1 job activity to Job2 job activity.  In the Job1 job activity go to the Triggers tab and change the trigger type to "Failure". Close and compile. You're done.